# UIWebView not opening the secured url

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, payment-gateway

In an iPhone application, I created a `UIWebView` which loads `http://www.google.com` successfully.
But the same web view is not loading `https://xxxseal.xxxxbank.com/mpi/Ssl.jsp?transactionId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` (a payment gateway URL), but this same URL is opening in Safari and other browsers successfully. Can anyone explain and help me in this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use NSString's [`– stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a) method to properly format the string before turning it into a NSURL.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
NSString *postString;
postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxxseal.xxxxbank.com/mpi/Ssl.jsp?transactionId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]; 
postString = [postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[WebViewObj loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]]];
```